# Flexslider: How can I display image captions in my node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, gallery, flexslider, image-gallery

I have a site where my nodes (articles) can have multiple featured images. By default, my articles have this gallery at the top of the page rotating through the images. I like it. I'd like to know where I can go to modify it, though, since I'd like to display caption information as well.

This is what my article node looks like (though I haven't added all the styling yet):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c62wg8w0b52o48z/t1.PNG?dl=0

This is the information for the images in my article node:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jglmo1ogm6jg2xs/t2.PNG?dl=0

As you can see, I have a Title, Alt, and Caption for each image. The title appears below the image by default. I'd like to display that caption, especially, somewhere near the image.

In my display settings under "Manage Display", I was able to select a bunch of different ways of displaying this gallery. I chose FlexSlider, and there's an option for displaying the image title (which exists no matter what I pick), but none for caption:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4cz4audj9o6p6w/t3.PNG?dl=0

Here's a live version of the page:
http://ccdrupal.dor.org/articles/multi-image-test#

Is that something that's easily done? I don't think this is the theme's functionality, but maybe it is. I'm using the Blogger theme for D7. Is there an extension that can do this? Is there something I should look for or change in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out that flex slider plugin and what template files it provides. Try finding and overriding template file that displays the image. Idea is to find how image is printed and image source is collected and use the same way to collect image caption field. Then you can add some extra HTML to print image caption.